# flink sql how to do explode(array)=== if we use array to pase a json how to do explode () in flinksql---does flink support explode

Tags: apache-flink

see example :
create table conv (
SM ROW(objectType STRING, verb string, actor ROW(orgId string), object ROW(contentCategory string, links ARRAY<ROW(ecmType STRING)>)),
`timestamp` string

)
WITH (
'connector' = 'kafka', -- using kafka connector
'topic' = 'sj1_spark_conv_hdfs',
)

how to use explode on SM.object.ecmType instead of using ecmType[1]

Comment: standard explode query: in spark:SELECT 
  coalesce(joined.orgId, 'unknown') AS orgid, 
  coalesce(joined.id, 'unknown') AS userid, 
  'join' AS activity, 
  SM.object.id AS spaceid, 
  timestamp AS time_stamp, 
  convertTime(timestamp) as pdate 
FROM 
  SOURCE_VIEW LATERAL VIEW explode(SM.object.participants) t AS joined 
WHERE 
  appname = 'conv' 
  AND SM.objectType = 'activity' 
  AND SM.verb = 'create' 
  AND SM.object.objectType = 'conversation' 
  AND array_contains(
    SM.object.participantTags, 'ONE_ON_ONE'
  ) != true 
  AND joined.personType = 'PERSON'

Comment: this is straightforwad using datastream api 'ss flatmap. to do it in flink sql , is it been done?